# how to pass mp3 stream/response to view from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net application and I am making a call to controller action from my view. this view need to return mp3 to called function. What will be type of Actionresult.  The function which is being called returns mp3 response. How to hold mp3 response in memory returned by api in memory and return to view ?

here is my controller method code:

```
 public ActionResult getrecording()
        {
            byte[] file = new byte[100]; // Convert.ToByte("https://api.abc.com/api/v2/GetRecording?access_token=dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfdsf");


            //return (new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "audio/mpeg"));
            ////return (new FileContentResult(data, "audio/mpeg"));
        }
```

and here is the view code

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function (event) {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                          mp3: "/recording/getrecording" 
                    });
                },
                swfPath: "../../Content/JPlayer/js",
                supplied: "mp3",
                wmode: "window",
                size: 100,
                duration: "#duration"
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a WebClient to download the remote file and then stream it to the response:

```
public ActionResult getrecording()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.abc.com/api/v2/GetRecording?access_token=dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfdsf");
    return File(stream, "audio/mpeg");
}
```

and if you want the client to be prompted to download the file simply add a name:

```
public ActionResult getrecording()
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    var stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.abc.com/api/v2/GetRecording?access_token=dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfdsf");
    return File(stream, "audio/mpeg", "foo.mp3");
}
```

Comment: I dont want to downlaod it. I want to pass mp3 response to jplayer http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-size

Comment: in my jplayer code , which I added in question, If i do like this:    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                          mp3: "https://api.abc.com/api/v2/GetRecording?access_token=dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsfdsf" 
                    }); It works but I need to pass access key and tokens which is not safe as user can see them.

Comment: You should point the url of jPlayer to your controller action: `mp3: '/somecontroller/getrecording';` and not to the remote service.

Comment: It works but in this case mp3 will be loaded on my server and i have lots of traffic so this will be burden on my server.

Comment: The traffic will indeed go through your webserver now and you will be paying for the bandwidth. You will have to make a compromise between security and price then.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for traffic, then you'll have to return a RedirectResult instead.